# What is the complexity for std::upper_bound and std::lower_bound for Vector in C++?

Tags: c++, stdvector, lower-bound, upperbound, lis

What is the complexity of the `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` functions.

I know in case of `std::set<int>` it is `log(n)`, but I have no idea for a `std::vector<int>`.

I was going through an implementation of the Longest Increasing Subsequence using vectors and `std::lower_bound`.

What is the complexity of this code?

```
int LIS2(vector<int> a) {
    vector<int> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        auto it = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), a[i]);
        if (it != v.end()) 
            *it = a[i];
        else 
            v.push_back(a[i]);
    }
    return v.size();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please embed your code as a text because images make it unnecessarily difficult to read and reproduce by others.

Comment: Downvoting for a screenshot (not even cropped well) instead of text.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I stand corrected. I will delete my comment as to not confuse anyone in the future.

Comment: the code is visible now

Comment: "Also, please tell me the complexity of this code". Can you ask this in a separate question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound:

> Complexity
>
> The number of comparisons performed is logarithmic in the distance between first and last (At most *log<sub>2</sub>(last - first) + O(1)* comparisons). However, for non-LegacyRandomAccessIterators, the number of iterator increments is linear.

For random access iterators (e.g from `std::vector`) the bounds functions simply do a binary search.

For non-random access iterators (e.g. from `std::list` and `std::set`) the functions still perform a binary search but there is an additional cost as they have to increment the iterators one element at a time to move between elements.

Comment: binary search  got  just `O(log n)` in worst case

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) `log2(n) +1` comparisons is correct (see the `performance` section), that is the exact complexity of the algorithm. The big O notation is an approximation (i think?) `log2(n)+1` is of the same order as `log(n)`

Comment: true, the algorithms runs in logarithmic time, but that's iterations counts, not comparison. The space complexity is still considered space complexity of binary search is `O(log n)`. Suppose that `O(1)` may account for it.  To e honest I though you meant  power of two with that space after `log`, which would be sorting complexity or roughly complexity of bound function run on a list or set

Comment: the text of the quote is just copied from the link